# Blocked ports/port forwarding to computer in my home network

Tags: port-forwarding, isp

I'm an electronics tech by trade, I know enough about networks/traffic/commands/etc. to do basic troubleshooting and know when I need to get help and what I'm looking for when I need it.

So, I don't currently have a router on my home network, which was pretty much just my PC up until recently (I am going to be installing one). So, I'm getting all of my traffic directly from my ISP's server.

I installed a Samsung camera system and Samsung has a DDNS service that is (supposed) to allow me to access the system from anywhere.

Problem is, my DVR can get out to the Samsung server and update it's settings in the server, but the server can't get back through my ISP to the DVR.

I can access the DVR from inside my network.

And I have changed the port on the DVR to a number >1024, but I've also tried 80, 81, 8080 and 8000, all with no luck.

One thing that I did notice was that when I set the DVR to port 80 and the try to login from the Samsung site, the login prompt for my ISPs server pops up, so it's almost like the the traffic is going directly to the ISP server and stopping there, i.e., the ISP server isn't forwarding the traffic into my network.

Samsung Tech support says that I need my ISP to unblock the ports I am using and port forward. However, when I talked to the techs at the ISP (it's a local one, not one of the big-name ones), they claim that no ports are blocked and that the just server passes through all of the traffic, so no port forwarding is needed.

I found a port scanner (Open port check tool) and when I check the IP that faces the world, all of the ports except 80 are closed.

From thinking about it, I see one of four potential things:

1) The server isn't getting past the ISP server for some reason (i.e., the ISP server isn't sending the traffic to my DVR's IP address);

2) My ISP is just blocking all of the ports;

3) I need a router on my end to get the traffic to my DVR (which really doesn't make a lot of sense to me, since everything else works fine);

4) I have no clue...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You say you have a network, but say you dont have a router, this contradicts itself. Please detail your setup properly, preferably with a diagram

Comment: As @Linef4ult says… no router == no internet. There must be one somewhere, even if you don't have physical access to it. Note, most domestic modems are also routers. If they have wifi, they are *definitely* routers.You need to be able to access it somehow to enable port forwarding for your DVR.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I'm using the ISPs router, when I say I don't have a router, I mean one not provided by the ISP.  My traffic comes through the ISPs server, through their gateway and to my computer(s).
So they are claiming that their router just passes all traffic, with no ports blocked and doesn't require any port forwarding. 
So, that's where I'm stuck, the traffic to and from any computer in my house gets in and out, and the DVR can get traffic out, but apparently can't get into it.
I don't know if it's significant, but my outside ip is 218.x.x.x and the gateway ip is 172.x.x.x.

Comment: Did you lose your original account? You might want to register so that you can have only one account.

Comment: it can't get in because you **do** need port forwarding - otherwise the outside connection doesn't know where to go, & the router isn't just going to let it search round for itself til it finds it.

Comment: @Tetsujin - thank you, so I'm not (totally) crazy.  So, do (can) the server and/or gateway actually pass all traffic and I just need to install the router and set up the port-forwarding or does the ISP still need to do forwarding even if I install the router?

Comment: Your ISP ought to forward all traffic. Your router should be capable of port forwarding required traffic, but it won't by default. You need to figure out how to access it & tell it.